# Why I can not upload file to my database?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to create a form about companies with couple of information (as you can see down below), but every time I want to upload a new row I get 1's in every column.

So, I want to know what should I do with my code?

```
        <?php 
        include('mysql.php');

        if ($_POST) {
                 $companyName = isset($_POST['cname']);
                 $address = isset($_POST['address']);
                 $phoneNubmber = isset($_POST['phoneNubmber']);

                      $result = $connection->query("INSERT INTO `companies` 
                      (`name`, `email`, `phone`) VALUES('$cegnev ', 
                     '$address', '$pn')");

    header('Location: http://localhost/phptest/test.php');

    mysqli_close($connection);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" tpe="text/css" href="urlapcss.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
        <form id="reg" action="test.php" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Form</legend>
                <ol>
                <li>
                        <label for="cname">Name of the company<em>*</em></label>
                        <input id="cname" type="text"  name="cname"/>
                    </li><li>
                        <label for="address">Email<em>*</em></label>
                        <input id="address" type="text"  name="address"/>
                    </li><li>
                        <label for="phoneNubmber">Phone number<em>*</em></label>
                        <input id="phoneNubmber" type="text" name="phoneNubmber" />
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Here is the table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNmKu.png)

Btw, the mysql.php, if you wondering what this .php file contains :

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$userName = "root";
$password = "";
$DBname = "hgeza06";

$connection = new mysqli($host, $userName, $password, $DBname);
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die("Error");
} else {
    echo "Succes!";
}
?>
```

Comment: `isset` returns a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isset($_POST['cname'])` - will return `1` if you have `$_POST['cname']` or `0` if you don't have it.

A better way will be :

```
$companyName = isset($_POST['cname']) ? $_POST['cname'] : '' ; //add a empty value if is not filled
$address = isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : '';
$phoneNubmber = isset($_POST['phoneNubmber']) ? $_POST['phoneNubmber'] : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, your variable names are inconsistent.  You create a variable called `$companyName` and then try to use it as `$cegnev`.  Same problem with your `$phoneNubmber` variable (which itself also contains a typo).  Use the variables that you define.

Once that's corrected... This return a boolean (true/false) value:

```
isset($_POST['cname'])
```

So you're literally inserting `true` and `false` values into your database, which get interpreted as `1` and `0`.  Get the actual values:

```
$companyName = $_POST['cname'];
```

Use `isset()` to determine conditionally what you want to do if the value is or is not set, but don't use it to try and get the value itself.

Finally, **and this is important**, your code is *wide open* to [**SQL injection**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).  (Or is about to be anyway, and it's by coincidence and error alone that it isn't *currently* open to it.)  There is [great information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) on what to do about that.  This is important because SQL injection vulnerabilities are both a major security hole (and thus a bad habit to allow to continue) but also a very common source of bugs and unexpected behavior in code.

Comment: Thank you, I was kinda confused about what's isset does.

Comment: And also could you tell me why I can't add, just 1 row in my table?

Comment: @GézaHorváth: It's not clear what you mean by that.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: In the database, i cant upload, just  1 row of information.

Comment: @GézaHorváth: It's still not really clear what you mean by "can't upload just 1 row".  But it does sound like a separate issue which merits a separate question, especially since this question already has an accepted answer.